# How to read details from File Properties in Windows 10?

Tags: c#, properties, fileversioninfo

I'm trying to read the "File Version" and "Product Version" file properties from an EXE file.

I'm trying to use the `FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo().FileVersion` function, but it doesn't return the full "File Version" property (For exmaple the actual file version 
 is "1.6.0.7" ----> and the `FileVersionInfo` function returns "1.6")

When I had Windows 7 installed on my PC I was using the following code which is working perfectly.

```
Shell shell = new Shell();
Folder objFolder = shell.NameSpace(Path.GetDirectoryName(strFileName));
FolderItem folderItem = objFolder.ParseName(Path.GetFileName(strFileName));
string fileversion = objFolder.GetDetailsOf(folderItem, 156)
```

On Windows 10 the above code is not working at all.

**Update #1 - As requested the complete code is:**

```
string fileversion = FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(@"E:\NewFolder\file.exe").FileVersion;
```

[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("1.0.0.0")]

**Update #2 - the following code does return the full version correctly**

```
FileVersionInfo fvi = FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo("C:\\MyFile.txt");
int major = fvi.ProductMajorPart;
int minor = fvi.ProductMinorPart;
int build = fvi.ProductBuildPart;
int revsn = fvi.ProductPrivatePart;
string q = String.Concat(major.ToString(), ".", minor.ToString(), ".", build.ToString(), ".", revsn.ToString());
```

Source: [Getting the program version of an executable file like explorer does in C# .NET 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17688660/getting-the-program-version-of-an-executable-file-like-explorer-does-in-c-sharp)

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11350008/how-to-get-exe-file-version-number-from-file-path

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get .exe file version number from file path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11350008/how-to-get-exe-file-version-number-from-file-path)

Comment: @Equalsk those answers don't help me.

Comment: Post your complete version code (and AssemblyFileVersion) including printing the file version. Something is likely wrong with your code. GetVersionInfo(<name>).FileVersion returns complete information.

Comment: @Dorel I don't believe you tried it properly, I can guarantee the code in the linked answer works perfectly fine on Windows 10 and returns a full version number of any exe.

Comment: @Ton Plooij as requested I have updated the question.

Comment: What does `fvi.ProductVersion` show compared to your string concatenation?

Comment: fvi.ProductVersion show the same result as fvi.FileVersion. For exmaple the actual file version is "1.6.0.7" ----> and the FileVersionInfo/ProductVersion function returns "1.6". problem solved.